# Getting strings from file gone wrong

Tags: c, file, gdb

The idea of this function is to get strings from file like this:

The file `CLIENTS_BOOK`: `client1,client2,client3`

and to get this in array of strings, eg:

- `CLIENTS_BOOK_ARRAY[i]` to be equal to `"client1"`
- `CLIENTS_BOOK_ARRAY[i+1]` to be equal to `"client2"`
- `CLIENTS_BOOK_ARRAY[i+2]` to be equal to `"client3"`

Here is the code:

```c
//global array
static char CLIENTS_BOOK_ARRAY[MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS][MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS];

void get_clients_string() {
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char *token;
    char help[256];
    FILE *InputFile;
    InputFile = fopen(CLIENTS_BOOK, "r");
    fscanf(InputFile, "%s", help);
    token = strtok(help, ",");
    while (token != NULL) {
        strncpy(CLIENTS_BOOK_ARRAY[i], token, MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    n = i;

    fclose(InputFile);
}
```

When I run it, it is giving
`Segmentation fault(core dumped)`
When running it with gdb it is giving

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f2ce38 in __strncpy_avx2_rtm () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

The interesting part comes when it is running as intended on my pc (Arch linux, amd cpu), and it does not on my laptop (Arch linux, intel cpu).

Comment: When you catch the crash in the debugger, where in *your* code does it happen? Have you looked at the `backtrace`? Have you tried walking `up` the call stack?

Comment: What is `MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS`? Are you sure it makes any sense to use same maximum number of string as the maximum length of the strings? They are rarely the same. Also why don't you verify if `fopen` succeeded?

Comment: When you get the crash in debugger I assume it is in the line with `strncpy` within your `while` loop. What value does `i` hold?

Comment: Did you `#include <string.h>`? I ask because `strncpy()` prototype is in there ... and if you didn't include the compiler will make erroneous assumptions about passing `MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS` around (32-bit vs 64-bit).

Comment: How long is your input file? You read everything up to the first whitespace with a single `fscanf`. Are you sure it will fit into 256 characters?

Comment: Post the full code, including the `#include` directives and the definition of `MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS`

Comment: https://github.com/milchevdimitar/dealer-advanced

Comment: "Post the code" means: "Post the code here in the question as formatted text. Remove unrelated parts and make it a minimum reproducible example"

Comment: When running with GDB you can select `get_clients_string` using the `bt` and `frame` commands, and then after that, `print` the values of variables to figure out what is wrong. For example you can do `print token`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not test the return value of `fopen()`. If the file cannot be open, `InputFile` will be a null pointer and `fscanf()` will have undefined behavior.
- `fscanf(InputFile, "%s", help);` will write beyond the end of the `help` array if the *word* in the file has 256 bytes or more. Use this instead:

  ```
  fscanf(InputFile, "%255s", help);
  ```

  or possibly:

  ```
  fgets(help, sizeof help, InputFile);
  ```

  and test for failure to read the file contents.
- `strncpy` is not your friend: `strncpy(CLIENTS_BOOK_ARRAY[i], token, MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS)` will not null terminate the string if it happens to be longer than `MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS - 1` bytes. Do not use `strncpy`, use `strncat`, `snprintf` or `strlcpy` if available instead.
- the loop does not stop at the end of the 2D array: you should check that `i <  MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS` in the `while` test.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CLIENT_SIZE    100
#define CLIENT_NUMBER  100
#define CLIENTS_BOOK   "client_book.txt"

static char client_book[CLIENT_NUMBER][CLIENT_SIZE];

int get_clients_string(void) {
    int n = 0;
    char buf[256];
    FILE *InputFile = fopen(CLIENTS_BOOK, "r");
    if (InputFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening %s: %s\n",
                CLIENTS_BOOK, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, InputFile)) {
        char *token = strtok(help, ",\n");
        while (n < CLIENT_NUMBER && token != NULL) {
            client_book[n][0] = '\0';
            strncat(client_book[n], token, CLIENT_SIZE - 1);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            n++;
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: no clients\n", CLIENTS_BOOK);
    }
    fclose(InputFile);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i dont need to return any value i fixed by closing the file outside of the function.

Comment: My full code is in the repo i posted. And i commited the change look for case 2 in the main switch. And tell me your opinion

Comment: The file is open inside the function, you cannot close it outside because the stream pointer is lost. Returning the number of clients is useful for the caller: otherwise scanning the array would be needed and wasteful.

Comment: Can u rewrite it so it looks like void get_clients_string(){
and doesnt return any value

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев: My remarks on the full code: `adress_book` and `clients_book` should have type `LinkedList`, not `LinkedList*`. `eliminate_the_first_element` should update `ll->tail` if removing the last or last but one element. `eliminate_the_last_element` should update `ll->head` in the same cases, There is no need for `eliminate_the_single_element`. `add_element_on_another_spot` should follow the `next` links and should stop on the last element. Your use of `strncpy` is still incorrect. `print_inventory` should test `INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[i][0]`, not `INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[i][i]`.

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев: `if(INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i] == '\0')` should be `if(INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i] == 0)`. `write_in_the_log_file` must close the file, otherwise you have a resource leak and will run out of stream pointers. Function `test` should stop at the end of the array. Same remark for many other functions, keeping track of the number of active clients would help and avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев: rewriting the function with prototype `void get_clients_string()` is trivial but counter productive: returning the number of clients is an improvement you should build upon and using `()` instead of `(void)` is incorrect as it makes the function accept unspecified arguments instead of no argument.

Comment: ```if(INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i] == '\0')``` musnt be ```if(INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i] == 0)```, because if i have zero from something I need to print 0 - but ```\0``` means that ```INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i]``` is empty. Should i do it like ```if(INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i] == NULL)```

Comment: Can i give you access to my repo to correct the things you are talking about, because i have no idea of what are you talking about ?

Comment: What is your github ?

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев: I will not correct all the problems I pointed to, it is your responsibility. You must hone your own C skills, it takes a lot of work to master the C language and any other language, but you have to start and learn by yourself. Look at the code along my remarks and try and understand what I am pointing to... If the code is not yours, transfer my remarks to the author and work together at improving it.

Comment: I get that. Do u have time to look up at it now - i ve rewrited it.